# Proof of hearsay about complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

I was talking to a friend today, he said that as one approaches a pole in the complex plane, you effectively reach the limit of every single complex number.

He is a bit nut, so I take every single thing that he says with a grain of salt, but the limit in the complex plane is quite similar to that for a 2D function, whereby the limit does not simply approach from one direction but from all direction.

Can anyone verify if there is some truth behind his statement?

Comment: It sounds like your friend is talking about [essential singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) and Picard's theorem. Their phrasing is a bit off though. This does not happen in the vicinity of a regular pole, where the function approaches complex infinity in the normal way. The values attained by a holomorphic function in any, no matter how small, neighborhood of an essential singularity form a dense set. And actually can omit only a single complex value. Of these two results the first one is easier to prove and the latter more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite true. In the case of a *pole*, such as $f(z)=\frac1z$ has at $z=0$, we have for example that $|f(z)|>1000$ for all $z$ with $0<|z|<\frac1{1000}$, so certainly $42$ cannot be reached as limit.

The function $f(z)=e^{1/z}$ also has a singularity at $z=0$, but this is an *essential singulkarity* (which merely says that it is not a pole). For such, we have [Picard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), which says that for any complex number $w$ (with possibly *one* exception), there exists a sequence $z_n\to 0$ such that $f(z_n)=w$ for all $n$. Of course, we can get rid of this "possibly one exception" if we merely desire $f(z_n)\to w$ (and we need only a result somewhat weaker than Picard to show this). This last statement sounds a bit like what your friend meant.